# Image of an accumulation point under a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff topological space and let $f:X \to F$ ($F$ can be assumed metric space) be a continuous map. Let $\left(x_n\right)$ be a sequence in $X$. Now, there are two possibilities:

1. $\left(x_n\right)$ is eventually constant, i.e., $x_n=x_0$ for all but finitely many $n$.
2. We can think of $\left(x_n\right)$ as an infinite set in $X$, which has an accumulation point in $X$, say $x_0$.

Now, what can we say about $f(x_0)$?

**Can we say that the sequence $(f(x_n))$ converges to $f(x_0)$?**

A detailed answer will be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume that $X$ is $T_1$.

In the first case it is clear that $f(x_n)=f(x_0)$ for all but finitely many $n$ and hence that $\langle f(x_n):n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ converges to $f(x_0)$.

In the second case it need not be true that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ even has a subsequence that converges to $x_0$. However, if $F$ is first countable (and hence in particular if it is metrizable), there is a local open base $\{B_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ at $f(x_0)$ such that $B_{n+1}\subseteq B_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. For each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $U_n=f^{-1}[B_n]$; each $U_n$ is an open nbhd of $x_0$, so $U_n\cap\{x_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\}\ne\varnothing$.

In fact, since $X$ is $T_1$, $U_n\cap\{x_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ is infinite for eack $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. This means that we can recursively construct a subsequence $\langle x_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ of $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ such that $x_{n_k}\in U_k$ for each $k\in\Bbb Z^+$ and hence $f(x_{n_k})\in B_k$ for each $k\in\Bbb Z^+$. This construction ensures that $\langle f(x_{n_k}):k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ converges to $f(x_0)$ in $F$. However, there is no guarantee that the sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ converges to $f(x_0)$.

Comment: Thanks @BrianM.Scott. Let you know, once I digest it.

Comment: @srm99: You’re welcome.

Comment: "In fact, since $X$ is $T_1$, $U_n\cap \{x_k: k\in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$ is infinite for each $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$"! Why is so? @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @srm99: Because in a $T_1$ space finite sets are closed, so for any finite $A\subseteq\{x_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\}$, there is an $m\ge n$ such that $A\cap U_m=\varnothing$. But $U_m\cap\{x_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\}\ne\varnothing$, so there must be a $k$ such that $x_k\in U_m\subseteq U_n\setminus A$.

Comment: Therefore, we can say:  Let $X$ be a $T_1$ compact topological and let $Y$ be a metric space. Let $f:X\to  Y$ be continuous. Let $x_0$ be an accumulation point of an infinite set $\{x_n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ in $X$. Then $f(x_0)$ is an subsequential limit of the sequence $((f(x_n))$ @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @srm99: Yes, that’s right.

Comment: Oh! Thank you for your constant help!@BrianM.Scott

Comment: @srm99: You’re very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

A bijective continuous map from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism.

Thus every open set $U\subset X$, $f(U)$ is open in F. So, if every open set containing $x_0$ interests X (limit point), the image of those open sets (containing $f(x_0)$ )will also intersect $f(X)$.

Comment: Your assertion that "continuous image of a compact set to a Hausdorff space is homeomorphic" is false. For that you need your function to be bijective. Best examples are constant functions @ryuzaki

Comment: yeah true, my bad

Comment: However, thank you for your trial:) @ryuzaki