# Weak$^*$ limit in Banach spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, solution-verification

It is known from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4083760/image-of-an-accumulation-point-under-a-continuous-function) that

**Result**

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff topological space and let $f:X \to F$ ($F$ can be assumed metric space) be a continuous map. Let $\{x_n:~n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ be an infinite set in $X$ with an accumulation point $x_0$. Then $f(x_0)$ is a subsequential limit of the sequence $(f(x_n))$.

**Present problem**

Suppose $A:=\{x_n^*:~n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is an infinite set of unit vectors in a topological dual $X^*$ of a Banach space $X$. Let $x_0^*\in B_{X^*}$ be an accumulation point of the set $A$ (Note that $B_{X^*}$ is weak$^*$ compact by Banach-Aloaglu Theorem, so existence of accumulation point is guaranteed) and let $\psi:X\to X^{**}$ denote the canonical embedding. Show that for any $x\in X$, $\psi(x)(x_0^*)$ is a subsequential limit of the sequence $(\psi(x)(x_n^*))$.

**Possible Solution**

Given any $x\in X$, obviously, $\psi(x)$ is a function from $X^*$ to $\mathbb{C}$, which is weak$^*$ continuous. Since $B_{X^*}$ is weak$^*$ compact and weak$^*$ topology is Hausdorff, by above result, we can find a subsequence of the sequence $(\psi(x)(x_n^*))$ that converges to $\psi(x)(x_0)$.

Is my solution correct? or, am I missing anything? Any help will be appreciated.